# Gcloud compute SSH connects to a different Instance than SSH + certificate

Tags: ssh, gcloud

So I'm trying to connect to a gcloud instance where I've installed several packages and started to develop my code with no problem. During the week, I use a certificate and putty to login since I work with a windows machine.

However now that I'm home, I tried to connect to the instance using my mac where I installed the Google Cloud SDK and after configuring all the parameters using

```
gcloud init
```

I get logged to an empty instance that doesn't have all of the packages and scripts I mentioned above.

What am I doing wrong? I can confirm that I'm connecting to an instance with the same name, in the same region and all, but it is completely different.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

As you are connecting from a different machine, that's a different user.

Go to /home, and check if there is a folder with the "other" username. Note that you might not be able to access. You would need to become superuser.